# I have installed WordPress on the same directory of live website

Tags: wordpress

By mistake, I have installed WordPress on the same directory of a live website from the application launcher in GoDaddy. But after a couple of seconds, I could realize and disconnected the internet and logged out from c-Panel. After that, I can see my website taking much time to respond, or loading lately and creating PHP process. Although, I'm not sure how many files are overwritten/duplicated. Is there any way I can check?

Comment: Why would you want to check? Just play back your last backup and all is fine.

Comment: @arkascha :-() A backup, whats a backup

Comment: Is your current live website using Wordpress as well? If not what is it based on?

Comment: @arkascha Thanks for the comment. Yes. I have auto backup and when trying to re-install that showing some prob.

Comment: @BenKelly The current website is WordPress. Here is the issue I faced. My website www.techgenyz.com is already live and was working fine. In my GoDaddy C-Panel I was working to install wordspress in another domain called www.tecognition.com, but instead of installing the wordpress in tecognition I installed in techgenyz.com(which is live site) in the same directory(root) but while I realised I disconnected the internet after couple of seconds. But in the C-Panel file manager I saw some files duplicated. After this I see website in not loading or WP posts are not opening.